# MYSQL adding rows with the help of sum()

Tags: php, mysqli

I want to create an SQL statement, where all the entries for my total_questions are added together, then I want to display that number.

My SQL looks like that:

```
<?php
  include ("../script/db_connect.php");

  $quiz_percentage_total = 'select sum(total_questions) as total from quiz_result where '
               . 'quiz_creator = ' 
               . $_SESSION["id"];

  $quiz_percentage_total_number = mysqli_query($con, $quiz_percentage_total);

  $show_quiz_percentage_total_number = mysqli_num_rows($quiz_percentage_total_number);

  mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

My HTML is empty except for all the necessary HTML information, the HTML code is:

```
<?php echo $show_quiz_percentage_total_number; ?>
```

Did I use the wrong variable to display or is there another mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call a fetch function to get the data from a query.

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, $quiz_percentage_total);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$quiz_percentage_total_number = $row['total'];
```

The number of rows will always be `1`, there's no point in calling `mysqli_num_rows()`.

Comment: Thank you, that helped me the most!